# Convert hex String to decimal string in C

Tags: c

How would you convert a hexadecimal string, like "661efdf2e3b19f7c045f15" to the decimal string "123456789123456789123456789"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is using external libraries allowed?

Comment: Yes if there is one

Comment: You will need some kind of big number math library or your own implementation.

Comment: The standard one is GMP.

Answer (score 2):

Using GMP you can assign the hex number to an "mpz_t" the GMP integer value. Here's an example.

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    mpz_t integer;
    mpz_init(integer);

    mpz_set_str(integer, "661efdf2e3b19f7c045f15", 16); //16 is the number base
    
    gmp_printf("Your number is: %Zd\n", integer); //Outputs "Your number is: 123456789123456789123456789"

    return 0;
}
```

GMP comes automatically with some linux distros but if you don't have it, you can download it [here](https://gmplib.org/).

Hope this helps!